# Penetration testing Windows Phone 8 apps w/o source

Tags: penetration-test, windows-phone

I am interested in performing a penetration test of a Windows Phone 8 application for which I do not have the source code. While I can easily validate network communication security, it is more difficult to validate that the application is not storing any sensitive data insecurely.

Because there is no public jailbreak/root for Windows Phone 8 at this time, this seems to be a difficult task.

I considered that if I could install the app into the Windows Phone 8 emulator/simulator that I could use WinDbg, [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/), maybe [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645), or even [API Monitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor) to determine where files are being written/read in the simulator's file system.

My purpose is to ensure a Windows Phone 8 application enforces security as this application claims, and it is difficult to perform a penetration test without root/SYSTEM access to the device.

Is it possible to monitor a Windows Phone 8 app's filesystem activity either in the simulator or on a device (without the app's source)? If so, how?

Comment: More comments here: [ReverseEngineering StackExchange](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1977/how-can-i-debug-or-monitor-a-windows-phone-8-application)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it is possible to [jailbreak a windows 8 phone](http://windows8jailbreak.com/).  Seeing as Microsoft can't keep people from [pirating games for the XBOX 360](http://thepiratebay.sx/browse/404), I don't expect Microsoft to be able to put up much of a fight in the jailbreak war.

A jailbroken device isn't the only way to conduct analysis of a mobile app. You can [decompile Windows 8 apps](http://lordhanson.wordpress.com/2012/10/13/decompiling-windows-8-apps/)  which can shed light in their inner workings.  As with iOS and Android hacking,  you can MITM SSL/TLS connections by [importing an your own certificate](http://blog.whichssl.com/2013/03/how-to-install-ssl-certificate-in-windows-8/) and intercept requests using a program like BURP.

Comment: I assumed Windows Phone 8 OS was different than Windows RT...am I incorrect?